# how to create a loop to get data continuesly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a database that has an id_parent and id_child, but the id_child may also be parents of more ids, p_1(parent_1) has child 1-4, c_1(child_1) has child 6-9

```
p_1
  |
 c_1 , c_2, c_3, c_4
   | 
  c_6, c_7, c_8, c_9
   |
   etc..
```

i have a function that gets the child by parent_id given a sql_table like so:

```
public function getChilds($folder_table, $folder_id){
            if($this->connect){
                $folder_id = $this->connection->real_escape_string((int)$folder_id);
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$folder_table.' WHERE user_id=\''.$this->user_id.'\' AND folder_id=\''.$folder_id.'\''; 
                if($results = $this->connection->query($sql)){
                    $obj = $results->fetch_object();
                    return $obj;
                }
            }else{
                $this->error = "Unable to connect to database. please make sure you can connect.";
            }
            return $this->error;
        }
```

is there a way to continue executing this function continuously execute this function like a pyramid until there isn't any more ids to be fetch from any ids?

**Attempt 1**
i got all ids in a array like so:

```
$array_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($array_ids as $key => $value){
    $new_ids = $obj->getChilds($sql_table, $value);
}
```

but this will only continue the process once more. i want this to continue until there isn't any more ids to get.

Comment: count the number of id's by `count()` then run a for loop till the count value

Comment: but that would work the same as the above loop, it will do it for each id of the current parent, it will not due it for the child's child ids

Comment: That is what i was looking for! i was running into a problem in my head, but i am unable to create it. can you give me a answer with an example to work from there?